# Using igraph on OSX installed via homebrew

Tags: macos, cmake, homebrew, igraph, clion

I am new for a C-programming and want to use igraph library.

I installed it via homebrew.

```
brew install igraph
```

After it i copy first example from igraph c tutorial in my main.cpp and change include igraph to

```
#include "igraph/igraph.h"
```

And Clion was suggest igraph functions and types.

Trying to build this a have error messages:

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build 
/Users/username/development/graph_clustring/cmake-build-debug --target 
graph_clustring -- -j 4
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable graph_clustring
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_igraph_destroy", referenced from:
   _main in main.cpp.o
  "_igraph_diameter", referenced from:
   _main in main.cpp.o
  "_igraph_erdos_renyi_game", referenced from:
   _main in main.cpp.o
  "_igraph_rng_default", referenced from:
   _main in main.cpp.o
  "_igraph_rng_seed", referenced from:
   _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
make[3]: *** [graph_clustring] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/graph_clustring.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/graph_clustring.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [graph_clustring] Error 2e
```

I think that I should fix my CMake file, and help CMake find lib isntalled via homebrew.

CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(graph_clustring)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(graph_clustring ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by adding target_link_libraries command to a CMake. It should look like this

```
make_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8) 
enter code here

project(graph_clustring)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(graph_clustring ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(graph_clustring, igraph.a)
```